# Challenging REGEX Problem to Address Medical Results Abstraction

Tags: java, regex

I have been unable to formulate a regular expression to extract the 1, 1S, 2, 2S, 3, 3S, 4A, 4AS, 4B, 4BS, 4X, 4XS and the potential add on of C to those multiples as well, from the Lung Rads Catagory in unstructured radiology reports, where the language may look like :

```
LUNG RADS CATEGORY 2
Lung RADS category 1, 
Lung RADS category 2. 
LUNG RADS CATEGORY 1
Lung RADS 3S.
Lung RADS Category 1:
Lung RADS Category 1 (S):
LUNG RADS CATEGORY 1 S
Lung RADS category: 2S.
Lung RADS: 2C
Lung RADS category 4B,
Lung RADS category 1S.
Lung RADS: 3.
Lung RADS category I
Lung RADS 2
LUNG RADS CATEGORY:I
LUNGRADS 2
LUNGRAD 2
LUNG-RAD 3
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `"Lung[ ]+Rads[ ]+Catagory[ ]+(\\d+[A-Z]*)"`

Comment: Thanks Edward but not working in this example:
https://regex101.com/r/fBodXP/1

Comment: Looks like your example works there

Comment: is this matching for you? Mine is showing no matches for this code?

Comment: I don't know englis good